# Latest tweets from a specific user (bonus: rotating slideshow)

Tags: 7, blocks, social-network

I want to display the latest 3 tweets on my homepage from my Twitter account for all users. A rotating slideshow of the tweets would be cool and it looks that with the Twitter module it might be possible but I can't get it working.

I have tried Twitter Block (http://drupal.org/project/twitter_block) but that is still under development and it seems the only thing not working with it is display a specific user (which is what I need).

I have searched far and wide, tried and tested a lot of modules and cannot find one that actually allows this. Does anyone have anything to point me at? Tutorial, walkthough, functioning module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would implement this:

1. Use [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to aggregate your tweets to a custom content type, map tweet id to node title and tweet body to node body.
2. Create a View to display x amount of tweets from the custom content type.
3. Use [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to rotate the content.

Comment: No problem, the beauty of this method is that it can be extended way beyond what most out of the box twitter modules can do without any additional coding.

Comment: Exactly. They seem kind of locked down in what you can do. This is great for pulling in data and manipulating to hearts content, plenty of possibilities with this technique (which is new to me).